# Getting tight on the deadlift makes me unable to do it for reps

Tags: deadlifts

I hear many famous poewrlifter say that one has to make their entire body tight before they do hte pull on deadlifts. Now, when I try doing this, I find myself very fatigued after the first pull itself. It seems much more comfortable to brace and rip the deadlift than so.

Is this max tightness advice only aimed for PRS or am I missing something?

Comment: maybe something is wrong with your setup?